# Show and hide tabs

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get a basic jQuery tabs solution working. I would like the tabs to render only when a link is clicked. Following the jQuery example [here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)  I can get the tabs showing no problem on my localhost, but as soon as I introduce a link to the page the tabs no longer render and instead the underlying tab content is displayed.

Looking through Stackoverflow I see answers suggesting the use of the hide() method but I don't know:

- if this is the way to do it - i.e. create the tabs on page load then
  hide them?
- whether I've used it correctly?
- Is it also possible to have a close button on the tab group (i.e. click the button and all the tabs disappear)?

My jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cvh2013/wYKVy/).

Javascript:

```
$("#tabs").hide();
$("#link").click(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="link">Link text</a>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Tab 1 text.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Tab 2 text.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>Tab 3 text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("tabs").show();` after you create the tabs, since you're hiding them in the first place.

See this http://jsfiddle.net/wYKVy/2/ for the button to close the tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You never actually instantiate the tabs. Try:

```
$("#tabs").tabs().hide();
$("#link").click(function () {
    $("#tabs").show();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SukBm/)**

Note that you could also do:

```
$("#tabs").hide();
$("#link").click(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs().show();
});
```

Comment: Also to follow-up on the second question you can change `$('#tabs').show()` to `$('#tabs').toggle();` and the link will now work to show/hide the tabs on click.

Comment: Thank you j08691, Stefan was just one miunte ahead of you but I've upvoted your answer as (a) it's correct and (b) it includes an eaxmple. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

## Try this out:-

**http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/wYKVy/3/**

## JS:-

```
jQuery(function () {

    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#ShowTabs").click(function () {
        $("#tabs").show();
    });

    $("#HideTabs").click(function () {
        $("#tabs").hide();
    });
});
```

## HTML:-

```
<a href="#" id="ShowTabs">ShowTabs</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="HideTabs">HideTabs</a>

<div id="tabs" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Tab 1 text.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Tab 2 text.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Tab 3 text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will sugest to try Tabbable nav from

[Bootstrap Nav](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar)

It would be much better and easier.

Comment: Thank you, that does look interesting.