# jquery to make unused tabs hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wai-aria

I have a template that I'm creating for colleagues to use in a WYSIWYG editor (am a teacher) with vertical tabs so they can easily add content to each one of them. Because they are using the WYSIWYG editor, I don't want them to have to deal with any HTML code. I want to add more tabs than what they would need to the template and then hide any tabs that only have "tab name" as the text in the tab. That way students will only see the tabs that have content in them.

The HTML code for the list-group is

```
    <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-3">
                 <div class="list-group flex-md-column text-center" id="tablist" role="tablist">
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 1</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 2</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 3</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 4</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 5</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 6</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 7</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 8</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 9</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab Name</a>
                    
                 </div>
              </div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Suggestions will be most appreciated.

Comment: This might help you learn something about tabs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664094/show-and-hide-tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just jquery:

```js
$("a[data-toggle=tab]").each(function(){ ($(this).text() === 'Tab Name') ? $(this).hide() : $(this).show()});
```

[DEMO](https://js.do/code/522844)

full html:

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js"></script></head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-3">
                 <div class="list-group flex-md-column text-center" id="tablist" role="tablist">
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 1</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 2</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 3</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 4</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 5</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 6</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 7</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 8</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab 9</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Tab Name</a>
                    
                 </div>
              </div>
          </div>
     </div>
     <script>
     function hideme() {
       $("a[data-toggle=tab]").each(function(){ ($(this).text() === 'Tab Name') ? $(this).hide() : $(this).show()});
     };
     function showme() {
       $("a[data-toggle=tab]").each(function(){ $(this).show() });
     };
     </script>
     <input type=button onclick="hideme()" value="HIDE"/>
     <input type=button onclick="showme()" value="SHOW"/>
</body>
</html>
```